# Can't upgrade Ubuntu Studio 19.10 Eoan to 20.04 Focal Fossa

Tags: upgrade, xfce, ubuntu-studio

I was trying to upgrade my Ubuntu Studio to 20.04 following the official guide here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades/UbuntuStudio
However when I get to the last step I reach an impass
When I run `pkexec update-manager` I get this answer:

`Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
WARNING:root:can not import unity GI Namespace Dbusmenu not available
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(update-manager:8042): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:43:29.466: cannot open display:`

And when I run `sudo do-release-upgrade -m desktop` it says that there's no new release found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded yesterday and I typed `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` And that worked for me.

Comment: `update-manager -d` should work as well.